# chess tournament, there are four groups, each containing an equal number of players.

Tags: linear-algebra

chess tournament, there are four groups, each containing an equal number of players. Each player plays against every other player belonging to one's own group exactly once; against each player belonging to one of the remaining three groups exactly twice; against each player belonging to one of the remaining two groups exactly three times; and against each player belonging to the remaining group exactly four times. If there are more than 1000 matches being played in the tournament, the minimum possible number of players in each group

Comment: I suggest you add some motivation for your question and also learn about [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @NotMath I don't see why you think that MathJax is relevant here. Are you really suggesting that this question would be significantly improved if the number 1000 were instead rendered as $1000$?

Comment: @Rani Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, [as is explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Please [edit] your question to give us more information, such as where you encountered this question and what you have tried so far. If you do not, there is a good chance that this question will be closed.